# Create Connetor CMIS BonitaSoft

Tags: alfresco, connector, bonita

I'm working with BonitaSoft Community version 7.6.3 and I want to create a CMIS connector to list the folders and documents for version 5.2 of Alfresco. I noticed that for this version of Bonita many connectors that existed in version 5.9.1 disappeared. When I asked the question how could I list Alfresco's folders and documents indicated that I would have to create a connector, however when reading the documentation for UI Designer forms it is not possible and that the solution would be REST API extension. When I analyze information about how to create REST API extensions it only gives Performance, Efficiency and Teamwork. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API extension [documentation page](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.8/rest-api-extensions) has been updated and now cover the community edition as well.

Note that connector are used when you need to interact between Bonita process execution and an external system. Execution of connectors happen on the Bonita server. When executed, a connector has access to a context that includes information about the current process definition, instance and task instance.

REST API extension are usually call from the user web browser. More precisely it is the forms or pages served by Bonita that will execute the REST API call. REST API is executed on the Bonita server but has no context information about the currently running process or task. If you need such information you need to provide them as part of the REST API extension.